How to Identify Equipment Churn from Laboratory Service Records Without Direct Churn Labels?
I'm analyzing a dataset encompassing 20 years of laboratory equipment service records, which includes the equipment ID, service dates, types of equipment (HOOD_TYPE), and descriptions of performed services (TASK_DESCRIPTION). This dataset varies widely in service frequency, from multiple times a year to once every few years, for different equipment types.
One challenge is the lack of explicit churn labels, which would indicate when equipment is no longer in use or hasn't required service for a considerable time. I aim to infer equipment churn indirectly through changes in service frequency or extended periods of inactivity.
Given the dataset's structure:

Each record logs the equipment ID, service date, and service type.
Equipment types (HOOD_TYPE) signify distinct servicing needs and frequencies.
The service frequency for equipment varies significantly.

The main hurdles include defining churn for equipment without direct indicators and addressing the variability in service frequency across equipment types.
I'm contemplating statistical methods or machine learning techniques to discern patterns or indicators of churn. I've considered survival analysis for time-to-event data, clustering for grouping similar service patterns, and anomaly detection to pinpoint unusual gaps in service.
Question: What approaches would best suit this analysis, considering the dataset's characteristics and the goal of deducing equipment churn? How can I account for the varied service frequencies when defining churn criteria?
Any guidance, including references to similar projects or methodological suggestions, would be highly valued.
